# How to diff a single, unstaged file in magit-status?

Tags: magit, git, diff

How can I display a diff for the actually selected file in `magit-status`?  What can I do  in

[image]

do display a diff of `build/conf/local.conf`?

With the now deprecated `git-status`, I could run `git-diff-file` (`=`) to see **quickly** what has been changed (without visiting the buffer first or digging through the the complete list of unstaged changes).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/17798109/324105

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Many sections in Magit can be expanded (and then again collapsed) by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Actually I was working on adding indicators to make that more obvious yesterday. Might try to finish that later today.